# c# datetime list sorted by date relative to current date

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, datetime

I have a list of events in C# webpages, which includes the properties

1. date (`DateTime`)
2. and description (`string`).

I want to sort this list by date, using LINQ, however I want to do this with the next closest date (to the current date) first in the list and the one furthest away last.
 So for example, if the date was 1st on Jan, the first in the list would be 1st Jan, and last in the list would be 31st December. 
Day and month are relevant, but year isn't.

I have researched this, but I am not really sure where to start.
 Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks for the all the answers and sorry my question was vague. I was trying to produce a list of events on dates, with the nearest dates at the top of the list - for example a list of birthdays - with the next upcoming birthday at the top, and the last upcoming birthday at the end. I'm sure my code can be taken apart, as I am by no means a professional - but this does what I need it to.

this was how I answered it in the end:

I created a class for events:

```
  public class Events
{
public int ContactId { get; set; }
public string Lastname { get; set; }
public string Firstname { get; set; }
public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public DateTime Now { get; set; }
public bool Reminder { get; set; }
public TimeSpan Difference { get; set; }
public int SortValue { get; set; }


public Events(int contactId, DateTime date, string lastname, string firstname, string description, bool reminder)
{

    ContactId = contactId;
    EventDate = date;
    Description = description;
    Reminder = reminder;
    Now = DateTime.Now;
    Lastname = lastname;
    Firstname = firstname;

    Difference = EventDate - Now;
    SortValue = Convert.ToInt32(Difference.Days % 365);
    if (SortValue < 0) { SortValue += 365; }


}
```

}

I then used the following in my code:

```
   var upcomingEvents = new List<Events>();

foreach (var eventt in db.Query("SELECT CONTACT_ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, DATE, DESCRIPTION, REMINDER  FROM CONTACTS INNER JOIN EVENTS ON CONTACTS.ID = EVENTS.CONTACT_ID WHERE CONTACTS.CUSTOMER_ID = @0", WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)){
    var newEvent = new Events(eventt.CONTACT_ID, eventt.DATE, eventt.LASTNAME, eventt.FIRSTNAME, eventt.DESCRIPTION, eventt.REMINDER);
    upcomingEvents.Add(newEvent);   
}
upcomingEvents = upcomingEvents.OrderBy(x => x.SortValue).ThenBy(x=>x.Lastname).ToList();
```

Comment: hey, do us a favor, write down 5 random dates, and then write down the order in which you want them. do it in your question. illustration is much more appealing than confusing words

Comment: Also, say your current date is June 16. Now do you want June 17 to appear before June 15 or after?

Comment: You question is pretty vague here, just a wall of text with one example that explains one side of your problem. Please improve it with more examples and also tell us what YOU have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
YourOrderedList = YourList.OrderBy(x => DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, x.Month , x.Day)).TotalSeconds);
```

This solution assumes that you want to sort the list of dates by their linear absolute distance from the current system date.

Comment: Thanks - I don't think this is quite what I was asking for, but it is my fault for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Without describing how to uniquely handle the case for dates in the past (before the "relative" date), it sounds like you just need to sort by date.  I think you are making this too difficult on yourself.